# What AppStore is my iOS/Android device connected to

Tags: android, ios, app-store

I've been asked by Saudi Arabia to exclude some features sensitive in their country (specifically features identifying homosexuality, if your curious).

So I'd like to localize the app based on which app store the user is connected to.

I've tried using NSLocale on iOS and java.util.Locale for Android but these appear to be more closely tied to the country of localization the user picks on their device (in the same general area where they pick the language for the device)

The problem with this, is that many people in Saudi Arabia buy their phones over seas (Great Britain being a common example) and they end up just changing the language to Arabic, but leaving the Locale as GB.  Or they just leave it in English with a Locale of GB.

So Locale seems like a poor choice for doing this type of localization.  Is anyone aware of an API that lets you determine which store your device is connected to?

Comment: How about creating two versions (normal and censored) and in iTunesconnect set their availability accordingly. People with iTune account from Saudi Arabia will only be able to access the censored version. This will not work properly in all cases, but it seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, instead of using **Locale** you may use **Core Location** framework. 
This framework will help you get country of the device your app is being used.

1. First step would be to use **CLLocationManager** class to get
   co-ordinates of device your app is being used.
2. Second step is to use **CLGeocoder** class to reverse geocode & get country details.

With this framework you would even get notified for any change in location if you wish to implement that.